# App that will help manage my contacts

Tags: web-apps

Is there an app that will help manage my contacts. For example, I just met with someone and I want to write a few notes about this person, maybe a particular date to follow up on an issue. The app should notify me on said date or it should notify me if I don't contact that person and/or should have canned messages to get in touch with a "what's going on?"

Does this exist? Someone said it's a CRM, but the CRMs I looked at where too dealflow based, not relationship based.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure about the next contact due functionality but a few people have started using [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) for their "[Farley Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farley_file)" as you can see from [this](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/25070-farleyfile/) discussion.

- Web Based
- Multi-platform, (OS-X, Windows, Linux, iOS, Android).
- Custom Tags
- Very powerful searches
- All of your notes on all of your devices
- Lots of other functionality such as web & pdf annotations, etc.
- Various pricing including Free (60MB of uploads/month), plus £20/year (1GB/mo) & premium £35/year (10 GB/mo).